# Rebasing/duplicating feature branch to an older release

Tags: git

I want to backport commits from one branch to one older branch. How should I do this? I know I could for example cherry-pick each commit one by one, but what would be the simplest way to do this?

*From this:*

```
___(a)__(b)__(c)__(d)__(e)__(f)__(g) <- master
    \    \             /
     \    (1)__(2)__(3) <- feature
      \
       (x)__(y)__(z) <- old release
```

*To this:*

```
___(a)__(b)__(c)__(d)__(e)__(f)__(g) <- master
    \    \             /
     \    (1)__(2)__(3) <- feature
      \
       (x)__(y)__(z)__(1)__(2)__(3) <- old release with feature
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, let's consider what a normal "rebase" onto the release branch would do here:

- git doesn't know that `master` is involved, so sees only two branches: a feature with commits `a-b-1-2-3` and a release with commits `a-x-y-z`
- the common branch point is therefore `a`, so the commits to be rebased will be `b-1-2-3`
- the new branch will end up as `a-x-y-z-b-1-2-3`, inserting commit `(b)` which in practice may be a large chunk of `master`

Luckily, the `git rebase` command has a form with three arguments, which [the manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) summarises as:

```
git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream> <branch>
```

But would perhaps better be explained as:

```
git rebase --onto <new-parent> <old-parent> <branch>
```

In your example:

- `<newbase>` / `<new-parent>` would be commit `(z)`: the point you want to graft commits onto
- `<upstream>` / `<old-parent>` would be commit `(b)`: the point where the commits you're interested in currently branch from (the current parent of the first commit you're interested in)
- `<branch>` would be the name of the feature branch which currently points to `(3)`, and which will end up pointing to the new rebased history instead

You can leave off the last argument, and it will just use whatever branch is currently checked out; if specified, it should be a branch name. The other two arguments can be anything that identifies a commit - a branch name, a tag name, or just a commit hash.

Answer (score 5):

You can run the `cherry-pick` command with a range for example `git cherry-pick b..3`. I would recommend this way if you don't want to change the branch pointer.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#git-cherry-pick-ltcommitgt82308203

Comment: I didn't know you could use `cherry-pick` with ranges. Nice.